# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx = \pi i $?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Silly question I should know the answer to, but what is the integral of:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx$$

I can use countour integrals to get one type of answer:
$$\oint\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx + \int_{arc}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx$$

Where here I assume that I am integrating over a contour that contains the pole. Choosing a parameterized path:

$$\int_{arc}\frac{1}{(x(t)-a)}\frac{dt}{dx}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(R e^{i t})} i R e^{i t}dx$$

$$2 \pi i  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx + \pi i \\
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx = i\pi
$$

But if I solve the problem using u-substitution:

$$ u = ln(x-a) \\
du = \frac{1}{x-a}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx = \int du = u = ln(x-a)|^{x\rightarrow\infty}_{x \rightarrow-\infty} = ln(\infty) - ln(-\infty)?
$$

since $ln(-\infty)$ is undefined, so what is going on here?

EDIT:
One of the answers points out that this integration only works when a isn't on the complex line. 
In the case where it is complex, (I think) we can do the following:

We breakdown our contour integral into more paths:
$$\oint\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a-\epsilon}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx + \int_{\gamma_2(t)}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx +  \int_{a+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx + \int_{arc}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx$$

Were we've broken down the path along the real line into 3 pieces, which looks like the following picture:

[image]

In the limit where we take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_3$ combine to approach the integral alone the real line. And $\gamma_2$ can be expressed as the integral:

$$\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{1}{(\epsilon e^{i t})} i \epsilon e^{i t}dx = -i \pi$$

which then gives us:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)}dx -i \pi + i \pi  = 2 \pi i\\
$$

So if it's on the complex plane the integral is $\pi i$ and its $2\pi i$ on the real plane

Comment: You should be able to get $P.V. \int_{-\infty}^\infty{\dfrac{1}{x-z_k}}dx = \pi i \space\mathrm{sgn}\left(\Im\left[z_k\right]\right)$ by performing a few contour integrations using infinitely long rectangle contours with infinitely small semi-circular excursions around the pole.  For the case of real $z_k$, with a u-substitution, that's a simple Cauchy principal value integral as @LL_3.14 mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your working.

1. Assuming $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the contour you chose is not suitable as $a$ lies on the border of the contour. This is not allowed - it must lie strictly inside the contour in order to apply Residue theorem.
2. The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x - a}$ is $\ln|x - a|$. Thus, what you should obtain is instead "$\ln(\infty) - \ln(\infty)$", which is not well-defined.
3. The function is not Riemann integrable as it is not bounded in $[-1,1]$, which is one of the requirements of Riemann integrability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Steps 2 and 3 I think I already understood, I was pointing out that it seems like there's a contradiction between the anti-derivative and whats calculated with contour integrals. Also, step 1 I think is a fair point, but does that mean that I am correct when my pole is not on the real line? Also I added a part that tries to cover what the answer is on the real line. Is that correct?

Comment: This integral is ill-defined since the integrand is not Lebesgue or Riemann integrable.

Comment: And there is no way to give a clear unique meaning to a divergent integral. Example $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n} x \mathrm{d}x = 0$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n+1}^{n+1} x \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n} x+1 \mathrm{d}x = \infty$

Comment: And this is the case for any complex number $a$.

Comment: @LL3.14, do you think you can explain exactly what makes this function not Lebesgue or Reimann integrable? And in general, when calculating Residues or Cauchy Integrals, I don't recall ever having to first check if the function is integrable. I guess I always should make this check?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = b+ic$ with $(b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. So first let us remark that the integrand is not Lebesgue integrable since for example using the fact that $x≥ b+|c| \implies c^2+|x-b|^2 \leq 2\,|x-b|^2$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^∞ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x-a|} &= \int_{-\infty}^∞ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{|x-b|^2+c^2}}
\\
&≥ ∫_{b+|c|}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2}\,(x-b)}
\\
&≥ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln(n) - \ln(|c|)\right) = +\infty
\end{align*}
$$
From this we deduce that the integral is also not Riemann integrable (as remarked by Clement Yung, if $a\in\mathbb{R}$, one also has that the integral is not Riemann integrable since it is unbounded, but more generally, Riemann integrability is only for bounded sets).

Since the integral is on an unbounded set and it is not Lebesgue integrable, the only way to give a meaning to the integral is by defining it as a limit, and different definitions might give different values. For example taking $a=0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty,\,\varepsilon\to 0 } \int_{-n}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} + \int_{\varepsilon}^n \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = 0
$$
by symmetry, but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty,\,\varepsilon\to 0 } \int_{-n}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} + \int_{\varepsilon}^{2n} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(2n)-\ln(n) = \ln(2).
$$
The same phenomenon occurs when you try to get the value of the integral as a limit of contour integrals. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Generalizations.

Other remarks: one usually use the Residue Theorem on bounded sets and then take a limit. Of course, on bounded sets, analytic functions are continuous and so there is nothing to verify. What your example shows, is that one can not take directly an infinite contour in general if the function is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So generally speaking, if there is a "pole" on the real line, that is what stops this Residue Theorem trick from working? But, if there are poles on the complex plane (not on the real line), then it works?

Comment: Also, under the condition we integrate ignoring the point where our function blows up, this CAN obtain a solution (albeit with a definition of 2 pieced-together separate integrals )? Is that result at least consistent with what Residue Theorem predicts?

Comment: No, the problem is the same for any $a$, I just choose $a=0$ as a simple example of diffferent values arising from different definitions because the computations are simpler in this case. The problem comes from the fact that the function does not decay sufficiently fast for large values of $x$.